# Rounding off values with greater number after dot

Tags: java, math

I have this code which gives a result

```
double a = 128.73;
double roundOff = Math.round(a*100)/100;
System.out.println(roundOff);
Result is :- 128.0
```

what I need that if the values after dot is greater than 5 i.e (6, 7, 8 or 9) then its
should give result by adding 1 to the given value that has to be rounded off, i.e

- 128.54 should give result to 128.0
- 128.23 should give result to 128.0
- 128.73 should give result to 129.0
- 128.93 should give result to 129.0

Comment: That's an odd way of rounding...

Comment: @Mysticial : yeah ... thanx for reply ...but i need the same.

Comment: @Mysticial yes, it is very odd, at least that first example has a typo.

Comment: Isn't it done automatically by Math.round this way? Just try Math.round(a) without any multiplication since you don't want decimale places. It should round up/down to next integer.

Comment: @PathFinder: You must specify whether your first example, 128.54 rounding to 128.0, is a mistake or not. People think this is likely a mistake because it is very rare and somewhat unnatural that there is a need to round fractions from 0 to .6 (exclusive) down while rounding .6 (inclusive) to 1 (exclusive) up. If you intended to write that 128.54 should be rounded to 129, not 128, then this is question is a duplicate, as marked. If you truly intend it to be 128, then this is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use [ROUND_HALF_UP](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#ROUND_HALF_UP) and [BigDecimal#setScale](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale%28int,%20java.math.RoundingMode%29)?

```
a = a.setScale(0, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
```

---

```
double myDouble = 55.2; //55.51
BigDecimal test = new BigDecimal(myDouble);
test = test.setScale(0, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
//test is 55 in the first example and 56 in the second
```

---

### EDIT

As @Alex noticed, the above code will not work as you wish. Here is another way using [Math#ceil](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ceil%28double%29) and [Math#floor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#floor%28double%29):

```
double n = myDouble - Math.floor(myDouble); //This will give you the number 
                                            //after the decimal point.
if(n < 0.6) {
     myDouble = Math.floor(myDouble);
}
else {
     myDouble = Math.ceil(myDouble);
}
```

Comment: It does not work for 128.54

Comment: Otherwise it doesn't make a sense. And from my experience in SO, **it is** a typo. If you're not sure, keep your -1 :)

Comment: After the proof about typo I will upvote, sorry :)

Comment: @Alex BTW - "*what I need that if the values after dot is greater than 5 i.e (6, 7, 8 or 9) then its should give result by **adding 1 to the given value that has to be rounded off***".

Comment: So, starting with 128.60 for that numbers (.6,.7,.8 or .9). I understand "value after dot" as 1 (first) digit.

Comment: @Alex Edited. It should be OK now.

Comment: If it was a typo, then this question has a dup that explains solving this using `RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN` (no need to reinvent the wheel using `floor` and `ceil`).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza But it's not.. That's why I used `ceil` and `floor`.

Comment: Then looks like homework, and 7 people fall in this trap of OP doing nothing than just posting a question and waiting for us solving the exercise =\

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza You're right. But since he proposed a "solution" (not really..) I though this might help him.

Answer (score 1):

try this, it is working

```
 double d = 0.51;
 DecimalFormat newFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.");
 double twoDecimal =  Double.valueOf(newFormat.format(d));
```

"#." = add # after decimal upto what place round off you need        .

Answer (score 1):

This works for all your numbers:

```
BigDecimal.valueOf(128.54).setScale(1, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)
          .setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have really such weired requirements use the folowing code

```
double value = 128.54;
double rounded = (((value * 10) + 4) / 10)
```

The value of `rounded` will then be `128.0`.
If the `value` is `128.64` then the result will be `129.0`.

If you have normal rounding (`.5` and higher rounds up) then you have to change the second line to

```
double rounded = (((value * 10) + 5) / 10)
```

The secret is that the constant (`4` or `5`) must be `10` minus the value from where it should be rounded up.

Answer (score -1):

1. `Math.round(a*100)` makes `Math.round(12873)` results `12873`
2. result of step 1 `12873` is a `long` typed value but not a `double` value.
3. So when it divides by 100, generates an `non-decimal` result `12873/100 = 128`.
4. Now it stores in a double variable as `128.0`.

> ```
> double roundOff = Math.round(128.54);
> System.out.println(roundOff);// output -- 129.0
> double roundOff = Math.round(128.23);
> System.out.println(roundOff);// output -- 128.0
> double roundOff = Math.round(128.73);
> System.out.println(roundOff);// output -- 129.0
> double roundOff = Math.round(128.93);
> System.out.println(roundOff);// output -- 129.0
> ```